# HTML5 Canvas Full Size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make html5 canvas full size through following code. I know there is other methods by using javascript but What's wrong in this?

```
<head>
    <title>Canvas_dot</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    #mycanvas{
       background-color : #d3d3d3;
    }

    </style>

</head>
<body >
    <canvas id=myCanvas  width=window.innerWidth height=window.innerHeight ></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With javascript, do this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xo42po77/)**

Comment: Why cant you directly access window object in DOM as done in the above code posted by author?

Comment: I have the same question.Cant we access window object in DOM?...Is it accessible only after the page is rendered??..

Comment: You can do it if you use inline javascript expression (onclick, onload, ...) via function. http://jsfiddle.net/xo42po77/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a solution, it can be actually made this way

```
  #mycanvas{
       background-color : #d3d3d3;
       width : 100%;
       height : 100%;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't set the height of the canvas to the weight of the window. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that window.innerWidth is actually Javascript. Javascript calls need a **script** tag around them for being recognized as Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A lot simpler and cleaner solution without JS. Just use:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#mycanvas{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color : #d3d3d3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several reason why this won't work:

1. JavaScript was made to manipulate DOM. For that to work the DOM need to exist before the element can be found. In this example the JavaScript code (see below) tries to manipulate a DOM element that does not exist yet (itself, ie. the canvas element) as the code exists *inside* the definition of the DOM element.
2. JavaScript is not recognized without defining `<script>` tags and tags cannot be inside another tag, so it's not possible to run the code in the *attribute* section of a tag (ie. `<tag <invalidtag ..> >`)
3. Anything after = is interpreted as a *value* to the key. The "window.*" is simply interpreted as a string, which for canvas in this case is an invalid value for width/height.

The closest you get to a valid setup to approximate this way of defining the tag is to use inline document.write(). In the HTML:

```
<script>
    document.write("<canvas width="  + window.innerWidth + 
                          " height=" + window.innerHeight + "></canvas");
</script>
```

However, due to its lack of maintainability, readability, security etc. it's recommended to define the size using the DOM element. If you need an initial state of the canvas filling the window you could do:

```
#myCanvas {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;  /* make sure html and body has width/height defined 100% */
    height:100%;
    }
```

This will however only update the canvas *element*, not its *bitmap* which is still 300x150 (unless a initial size was defined). When the script can run, update the bitmap size in JavaScript:

```
updateCanvasSize();
window.onresize = updateCanvasSize;

// assuming var canvas = ...element.. is already obtained
function updateCanvasSize() {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();   // get pixel size of element
  canvas.width = rect.width;                   // update bitmap which now match 1:1
  canvas.height = rect.height;
  // redraw content here as resizing the bitmap clears it
}
```